# How to change php version in bitnami lamp stack deployed on Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, cloud, lamp, bitnami

I have deployed bitnami lampstack with php version 8x on Google cloud. But my application built on PHP 7.2. so I want to change version of php to 7.2 from 8 in lampstack. Can it be possible? Else I need to install a new stack?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but complicated. If you wish to use Bitnami, select one of their stacks with PHP 7.2. However, I recommend that you install LAMP instead and install the versions you require.